# Discontinuous function of two variables

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

Let \begin{equation}
     f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation} be a function of two real variables given by
\begin{equation}
 f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
       \frac{x}{y} & \text{for}\quad y\neq 0  \\
       0 & \text{for}\quad y=0 \ \\
       \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Does $f(0,0)=0$? My understating is that $f(0,0) =0$ since $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. We have $f(0,0)=0.$

Comment: Here , $f(0,0) = 0$ , but the limit , $\lim {x,y \rightarrow 0} [ f(x,y) ]$ is "something" else !